# Problems with hasChild() using bolt compiler

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, bolt

**I need to verify that the 'category' attribute has its value equal to a key existing on the category node**

I tried this:

```
type VerifyCategoryExists extends String { validate() { prior(root.categories['categories-list'][this]) != null } } }
```

That generated this:

```
".validate": "(newData.isString() && root.child('categories').child('categories-list').child(data.val()).val() != null)"
```

But I wanted this (I tested without using the bolt and it worked):

```
".validate": "(newData.isString() && root.child('categories').child('categories-list').hasChild(newData.val()))"
```

How do I get to the expected result but using the bolt?

Answer (score 1):

After a long time, I tried it and it worked the way I wanted it

```
type VerifyCategoryExists extends String {
    validate() { prior(root.categories['categories-list'])[this] != null }
}
```